# Eclipse - Publish & Run Simple Web Project

Tags: eclipse

I must be missing something really obvious but I just cannot work out how to publish & run a simple JavaScript & HTML project to an Apache server on a local VM.

I have tried the locally installed Eclipse help but it always seems to come to an end without filling in the full details of what is required and there is no summary that gives a start to finish overview of what is needed to complete what should be a straightforward task.

My project is simple, it is comprised of links to a single JavaScript file and a directory of HTML files. I have created a server, giving the details of the Apache server on the VM, as far as I can tell I now need to link the project with the server but I can't work out how to do this task. If I right click on the project and go to `Run As/Configurations` the `Create, manage and run configurations` window allows me to create a new configuration but the server select box contains no servers.

I really have no idea whether that is what I need to be doing but I have tried so many options that I am now completely lost.

In the server window it says 'started, synchronised' by the server but it isn't even attempting to write files to the server directory (which is mounted on my file system).

I am using 'Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Developers' v1.4.1, 'Eclipse Platform' v3.7.1.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for publishing and running a simple JavaScript & HTML project on a local Virtual Machine?

Comment: "If I right click on the project and go to Run As/Configurations the 'Create, manage and run configurations' window allows me to create a new configuration but the server select box contains no servers." I had this same problem - go to Help -> Install New Software -> Navigate to the Eclipse WTP Repository in the top bar -> Look under WTP 3.3.2 or similar (not the SDK version) -> Install anything that looks like "JST Server Plugins" - there should be three options near the bottom of the folder. That made the Apache Tomcat servers show up for me.

Answer (score 20):

**Publishing Static Content and JavaScript on Apache Server using Eclipse**

> Add Server

1. Window -> Show View -> Servers
2. Right click inside servers tab
3. New - > Server -> HTTP Server -> Next
4. add publishing dir: in my case (C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs)
5. Next -> add port (12345 in my case)

> Create a web project

6. Switch to Web View (Right hand top corner)
7. Right click Project Explorer in left
8. New  -> Project -> Web -> Static Web Project
9. Name the Project
10. Select Runtime Target as HTTP Server
11. Next -> Notice your default context root
12. Finish

> Copy your current js and html files in the 'WebContent' directory in
>   Project Explorer.

---

> In Servers Tab

1. Right click HTTP Server
2. Add - Remove -> Add your project -> Finish
3. Right click Http Server -> Publish
   4 done!

---

You should be able to see your stuff in publishing directory.
you can access the page at

http://localhost:/context_root

cheers!

Comment: Does this answer require an installed and running Apache server? I wound up using HTTP Preview instead.

Comment: Yes It does.. When you add a server you have to set the directory your need to publish to.  It doesn't need to be a Apache though. Could be any directory that's being served out.

Answer (score 10):

Before going to run your web project, you should have any of the servers like Apache Tomcat, JBoss, etc.

1.Right click on your project - Run As - Run on Server

[image]

2.Consider currently there is no server configured into Eclipse, so you have to select the sever (consider you have Apache Tomcat server) and configured into Eclipse and click finish. The server will be starts automatically and the project will be running in Eclipse internal browser.

[image]

[image]

3.If suppose server is not started - right click on the server - in the below server tab - select start option.

[image]

4.There is a chance to fail the server start - the configured port in the server may be used by other server, so you need to change the server port - right click the configured server and click open - change the HTTP port 8080 to some other port.

[image]

5.Start the server

6.There is an option to check whether your project is deployed successfully in the server or not. Right click configured server and click Add and Remove option - There will be showing available web project and deployed web project.

[image]

Comment: The question is clearly about  Simple Web Project and you dont need Tomcat to run it. Tomcat is a Application Server and not a Web Server. Although putting it in tomcat would work, that is not a idea solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and was able to get it to work by doing this:

1) Delete the server you have in the Servers tab. Also go into the Preferences -> Servers -> Runtime Environment and make sure you have your server set up the way you want. If you are using a real web server for example, use an HTTP Server and specify the port, and the path of where to publish to (this is where it will write your stuff to).

2) Create a new server by right-clicking in the Servers tab. This will have you select the server you created (or used) in the Preferences (above) and then it will let you select the projects in your workspace to associated with the server.

3) Right click the server and select "publish", and you will see your artifacts in the directory that you selected for your server. You should now be able to access them with the server.

(It's not that easy to figure this out when you first get started, so I understand your frustration).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Step 1 does as I expect and the server is setup so that the destination is the folder for the remote server that is mounted locally, but there are no resouces in the list on the 'Add & Remove' page for the server when I create a new one. I'd hoped (not expected, I'm far beyond expecting anything at all) to see the project that I am working on. Maybe the project is of the wrong type, is that possible? How can I check or change it? I really wish I had stuck to TextMate!

Comment: That could be it, I created a Static Web Project for testing purposes. I think if you create any of the projects that allow for the web stuff you should be fine. You can just create a new project with the right type and copy your files to it.