# How to deploy a html or javascript app in Apache http server

Tags: eclipse, apache

Could you please point me towards some documentation about deploying  web application which consists of html and javascript to an apache http server instance using Eclipse ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adapted to latest Apache 2.4 using the instructions **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8629043/325742)** :

Requirements : Apache Server (I downloaded v2.4 from **[here](http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.apache.org//httpd/binaries/win32/)** )

**Publishing Static Content and JavaScript on Apache Server using Eclipse**

> Add Server

1. `Window -> Show View -> Servers`
2. Right click inside `Servers` tab
3. New - > Server -> HTTP Server -> Next
4. add publishing dir: in my case (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\htdocs`)
5. Next -> add port (8080 in my case)

> Create a web project

6. Switch to Web View (Right hand top corner)
7. Right click Project Explorer in left
8. New  -> Project -> Web -> Static Web Project
9. Name the Project
10. Select Runtime Target as HTTP Server
11. Next -> Notice your default context root
12. Finish

> Copy your current js and html files in the 'WebContent' directory in
>   Project Explorer.

---

> In Servers Tab

1. Right click HTTP Server
2. Add - Remove -> Add your project -> Finish
3. Right click Http Server -> Publish
   4 done!

---

You should be able to see your stuff in publishing directory.
you can access the page at

`http://localhost:<port>/context_root`

Also, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400752/config-apache-http-server-for-eclipse)** is a worthwhile read for this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot...!!:) It was of great help...:)